# How to quantify Td and Z0 for a given length of RG-58 coax cable in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, coax

I want to simulate a current source (on the left in below) is connected to a scope input via a meter long RG-58 coax cable. But, I cannot figure out what should Td and Z0 be.

[image]

I only found the coax has 82 pF/m capacitance and maybe a 1mOhm resistance per meter, but that is for low freq model. How can we set Td and Z0 for the above schematic?

Comment: Z0 is characteristic impedance, from the coax datasheet. Td= length * velocity where velocity is also in the datasheet, and usually around 2/3 * C. (You still have the problem of an absurdly high source impedance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the characteristic impedance is 50 Ω then you can calculate the inductance as:

$$L=Z^2C=(50\;\Omega)^2\cdot 82\;\text{pF}=205\;\text{nH}$$

Then the delay will be:

$$\tau_{_d}=\sqrt{LC}=\sqrt{205\;\text{nH}\cdot 82\;\text{pF}}=4.05\;\text{ns}$$

You can test this with both the lossy and the lossless transmission lines:

[image: test]

Looking [here](https://www.awcwire.com/rg-catalog/rg58-coax-cable) I see it has 29 pF/ft = 95.144 pF/m, and Z<sub>0</sub> = 53.5 Ω. Obviously, some specs might differ, so use whichever ones apply to you.

Comment: Thank you I hope you can have idea on this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590265/am-i-estimating-rs-correct-for-this-device-model